# Fast powering / Successive squaring algorithm moving too slow with larger amount of digits

Tags: python, algorithm, rsa

So, I'm attempting to implement a modular arithmetic fast-powering algorithm in Python, but I seem to be hitting severe bottlenecks. 
So, as I understand it, you're supposed to find a binary representation of the exponent and calculate the product of the base^2^i, where i is the number of binary digits.
My python code is an implementation of the definition of the algorithm usually seen online and in textbooks:

```
    def fastPower(base, exp, mod):
        base %= mod
        workingExp = exp
        product = 1
        upperBound = range(int(math.ceil(math.log(exp,2))))
        for i in upperBound:
            print upperBound
            binDigit = workingExp % 2
            workingExp /= 2
            binExp = (binDigit << i)
            product *= base ** binExp
            product %= mod
        return product
```

The bottleneck is at `product *= base ** binExp` because the powers of 2 end up getting really
large when you hit 20-bit numbers, slowing down the exponentiation to sub-fast powering speeds.
Is there something unique to modular arithmetic I'm missing in this implementation? Or perhaps I've put operations in poor places for optimizations?

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't want to use three-argument `pow`?

Comment: Mostly just for practice/pedagogical reasons. I would definitely use pow() as you suggested for doing more serious work, but I'm attempting to learn some number theory and cryptography by experimenting in Python.

Comment: This isn't how exponentiation by squaring works. I hope you realized something weird was going on when your "successive squaring" algorithm didn't have any squaring in it.

Answer (score 2):

Hm....I am more familiar with something like this:

```
def fastPower(base, exp, mod):
    if exp == 0:
        x = 1
    else:
        half = fastPower(base, exp // 2, mod)  # just / in Python 2
        x = half * half
        if exp % 2 == 1:
            x *= base
    return x % mod
```

It does have a little overhead due to recursion, though it is very clear and still fairly fast.

Or, if I wanted it to be fast:

```
def fastPower(base, exp, mod):
    return pow(base, exp, mod)
```